# Google SpreadSheets Api setup

Tags: android, google-drive-api, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api, google-authentication

I am creating an android app which will store data on spreadsheets for which I have used Drive and SpreadSheet APIs and have integrated just as their quickstart section suggests now the problem is that do I have to do all the authorization and getting permissions and checking google play services stuff everytime I want to interact with the api or is there a way to avoid this. Following is the code snippet that I have done till now.

```
public class SpreadSheetActivity extends Activity implements EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks {
    Button setup;
    EditText name;
    String name_var;
    GoogleAccountCredential mCredential;
    static ProgressDialog mProgress;
    static final int REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 1000;
    static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 1001;
    static final int REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES = 1002;
    static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_GET_ACCOUNTS = 1003;
    private static final String PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME = "accountName";
    private static final String[] SCOPES = {SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS, 
                  DriveScopes.DRIVE};


        @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_backend_google);
    setup=findViewById(R.id.setup_btn);
    name=findViewById(R.id.url);
    LinearLayout activityLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    activityLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
    activityLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    activityLayout.setPadding(16, 16, 16, 16);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams tlp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


    setup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            name_var=name.getText().toString();
            if(validateGoogle(name_var)){
                getResultsFromApi();}
                else {
                name.setError("Enter a valid name");
            }

        }
    });

    mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mProgress.setMessage("Calling Google Sheets API ...");

    setContentView(activityLayout);
    // Initialize credentials and service object.
    mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
            getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
            .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());
      }
     public  void getResultsFromApi() {
    if (! isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
        acquireGooglePlayServices();
    } else if (mCredential.getSelectedAccountName() == null) {
        chooseAccount();
    } else if (! isDeviceOnline()) {
        Toast.makeText(SpreadSheetActivity.this,"Please connect to internet 
      and try again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {

        new 
   MakeRequestTask(SpreadSheetActivity.this,mCredential,name_var).execute();


    }
}

    @AfterPermissionGranted(REQUEST_PERMISSION_GET_ACCOUNTS)
     public  void chooseAccount() {
    if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(
            this, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS)) {
        String accountName = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null);
        if (accountName != null) {
            mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
            getResultsFromApi();
        } else {
            // Start a dialog from which the user can choose an account
            startActivityForResult(
                    mCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(),
                    REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
        }
          } else {
        // Request the GET_ACCOUNTS permission via a user dialog
        EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(
                this,
                "This app needs to access your Google account (via 
       Contacts).",
                REQUEST_PERMISSION_GET_ACCOUNTS,
                Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS);
    }
    }

    @Override
      public void onActivityResult(
        int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES:
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(SpreadSheetActivity.this,"This app requires 
    Google Play Services. Please install " +
                        "Google Play Services on your device and relaunch 
    this app.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                getResultsFromApi();
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null &&
                    data.getExtras() != null) {
                String accountName =

          data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                if (accountName != null) {
                    SharedPreferences settings =
                            getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
                    editor.apply();
                    mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                    getResultsFromApi();
                }
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                getResultsFromApi();
            }
            break;
            }
       }
        @Override
       public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
       super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, 
      grantResults);
         EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(
            requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this);
       }
     @Override
     public void onPermissionsGranted(int requestCode, List<String> list) {
       // Do nothing.
      }

     @Override
      public void onPermissionsDenied(int requestCode, List<String> list) {
        // Do nothing.
     }

     public  boolean isDeviceOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager connMgr =
            (ConnectivityManager) 
     getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());
    }

    public boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
    GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability =
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    final int connectionStatusCode =

   apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(SpreadSheetActivity.this);
    return connectionStatusCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS;
}


     public  void acquireGooglePlayServices() {
    GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability =
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    final int connectionStatusCode =
            apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(connectionStatusCode)) {
        showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(connectionStatusCode);
    }
}

   void showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
        final int connectionStatusCode) {
    GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = 
 GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    Dialog dialog = apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(
            SpreadSheetActivity.this,
            connectionStatusCode,
            REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES);
    dialog.show();
}
     public boolean validateGoogle(String url_var){
    boolean valid=true;
    if (name_var.isEmpty()) {
        name.setError("enter a name for new Spreadsheet");
        valid = false;
    } else {
        name.setError(null);
    }
    return valid;
}
```

}
Now In asynctask class I am creating a spreadsheet after that I want to update data in that spreadsheet. Do I have to perform this all on every update? Or is there any way that I dont know?

Comment: Hi please follow this link https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/android and yes this performed every time.

Comment: I have done this. But now I want to submit data from android form so how can I pass the account credentials and other parameters from my activity?